# Data binding with x:Bind to a List in UWP app

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp

Fairly new to UWP but not to c# and having a databinding issue.
I am trying to produce a file list which I am sure is dead easy but I am obviously missing something.

I have ViewModel:

```
namespace FileThing.ViewModels
    class FolderContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public StorageFolder SelectedFolder;
    public ICollection<StorageFile> FileList;

    public async Task<bool> GetFileList()
    {
        if (SelectedFolder != null)
        {
            // Get the file list
            FileList =  (ICollection<StorageFile>) await SelectedFolder.GetFilesAsync();
            return true; // Success..
        }
        else
        {
            return false;  // there was an error
        }

    }

  more stuff....

}
```

My XAML looks like:

```
<Page
x:Class="FileThing.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:FileThing"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:data ="using:FileThing.ViewModels"
mc:Ignorable="d" FontSize="16" >

<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <TextBlock Name="NextStep" Text="Please Select a Folder to Process"/>
        <Button Name="FolderButton" Click="FolderButton_ClickAsync" Margin="20,20,20,20">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"  Text="&#xE8B7;"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Set Folder" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <!--<Button Name="FolderButton" Content="Set Folder" Click="FolderButton_ClickAsync" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>-->
        <TextBlock Name="SelectedFolderPath" Text="No Folder Selected"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <ListView x:Name="FileList" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemsSource ="{x:Bind fc.FileList}">
        <ListViewHeaderItem>
            <TextBlock Name="Status" Text="Nothing to report so far"/>
        </ListViewHeaderItem>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:FolderContext">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Name="Path" Text="{x:Bind FileList.Path}"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="FileName" Text="{x:Bind FileList.Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>


</StackPanel>
```

The Code Behind for the MainPage is:

```
   public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    FolderContext fc = new FolderContext();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

    }

    private async void FolderButton_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        fc.SelectedFolder = await Helpers.GetFolder();
        SelectedFolderPath.Text = fc.SelectedFolder.Path;
        Status.Text = "Loading Files ...";
        bool filesloaded = await fc.GetFileList();
        if (!filesloaded)
        {
            NextStep.Text = "There was an Error Please try again or select another folder";
        }
        else
        {
            Status.Text = "File List Loaded successfully with " + fc.FileList.Count + " files found";
        }
    }
}
```

So the user presses the Selectfolder button, the code successfuly does that and returns a list of 'StorageFile' objects - I have a seperate question as to whether StorageFiles are a bit too heavy for what I want (simple analysis but lots of files)...
My error is:
Invalid binding path 'FileList.Path' : Property 'Path' can't be found on type 'ICollection' FileThing
I have the same error for FileList.Name both of which are valid properties of a StorageFile Object. Referencing the Inner TextBlock lines of the ItemTemplate.

I have tried using other collection types; List, IList, ObservableCollection (preferred I think to save Inotifychanged harassment?, but I think I'm missing something more fundamental.
I am sure its a simple Newbie error - any thoughts ...

Comment: I have managed to make this work partially.. by basically putting the FileList in the MainPage code behind. But it doesn't work if I reference the fc class of type FolderContext and have the FileList in there... maybe you just cant reference sub objects... ? But that doesn't seem sensible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used the x:bind incorrectly. For a better understanding, I suggest you to learn from the [Data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/) topics and the [{x:Bind} markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) document.

{x:Bind} uses the page or user control itself as the default source. So it will look in the code-behind of your page or user control for properties, fields, and methods. Moreover, when using {x:Bind} with data templates, you must indicate the type being bound to by setting an **x:DataType** value and the **DataType** should include the corresponding properties, fields and method that you bind in the **DataTemplate**. You can also set the type to an interface or base class type, and then use casts if necessary to formulate a full expression.

For your issue, it should be more appropriate that your **x:DataType** is the `StorageFile` class and the `TextBlock` `Text` property could bind the `Path` and `Name` directly. The code will look like this:

```
<Page
    ...
    xmlns:storage="using:Windows.Storage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    ...
        <ListView x:Name="FileList" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemsSource ="{x:Bind fc.FileList}">
            <ListViewHeaderItem>
                <TextBlock Name="Status" Text="Nothing to report so far"/>
            </ListViewHeaderItem>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="storage:StorageFile">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Name="Path" Text="{x:Bind Path}"/>
                        <TextBlock Name="FileName" Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
     ...
</Page>
```

Comment: Thank you I did as you suggested and it does see the elements now. Only problem this then causes is that it seems difficult to cast the IReadOnlyList returned by the folder picker into an ObservableCollection<StorageFile> , the code builds and runs but hits an exeception.. :S -